# Generar random en JQuery sin repetir y añadirlo

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, random

Estoy creando una pagina web con diferentes actividades para niños y en una de las actividades te sale la palabra del numero que hay que clicar dando 4 opciones como respuestas (del cual una es la respuesta correcta):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo:

```html
 <div class="col-sm-8 actividad2 baseNumeros">
                            <div class="pantalla">
                                <label class="pres">ONE</label> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="resultados">
                                 <button class="resultado BotonReinoNumeros r1">
                                        <label class="clicar numeroclicat1"></label>
                                 </button>
                                <button class="resultado BotonReinoNumeros r2">
                                    <label class="clicar numeroclicat2"></label>
                                </button>
                                <button class="resultado BotonReinoNumeros r3">
                                   <label class="clicar numeroclicat3"></label>
                                </button>
                                 <button class="resultado BotonReinoNumeros r4">
                                    <label class="clicar numeroclicat4"></label>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                           
                    <div class="progress BarraAcitivdad2">
                            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info progress-bar-striped active PNumerosA" 
                            role="progressbar"></div>
                    </div>
                    
 </div>
```

He intentado generar un Random con JQuery, ademas de un While para ir comprovando las diferentes opciones pero no me acaba de salir:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var alargada = $('.resultado').length;

  var n1 = $(".numeroclicat1").text(1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6));
  var n2 = $(".numeroclicat2").text(1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6));
  var n3 = $(".numeroclicat3").text(1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6));
  var n4 = $(".numeroclicat4").text(1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6));

  while (n1 == n2 || n1 == n3 || n1 == n4 || n2 == n3 || n2 == n4 || n3 == n4) {
    if (n1 == n2) {
      $(".numeroclicat1").text(1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6));
    } else if (n1 == n3) {
      $(".numeroclicat3").text(1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6));
    } else if(n1 == n4) {
      $(".numeroclicat4").text(1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6));
    } else if (n2 == n3) {
      $(".numeroclicat2").text(1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6));
    } else if (n2 == n4) {
      $(".numeroclicat2").text(1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6));
    } else if (n4 == n3) {
      $(".numeroclicat4").text(1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6));
    }
  }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para resolver tu problema puedes cambiar la estrategia para obtener valores aleatorios de un conjunto de elementos cualquiera sin tener repetidos.

La idea es definir el conjunto de valores de los que quieres obtener valores aleatorio y sacar de ese conjunto el valor seleccionado, reduciendo el conjunto  cada "extracción".

Para implementar ésta estrategia puedes utilizar muchos tipos de datos, desde arrays, strings o lo que sea...

Yo te propongo un ejemplo que puedes adaptar facilmente a tu código y ademas, cambiando el conjunto inicial te sirve para proponer mas alternativas de juegos, por ejemplo con letras...

```
var misElementos = "1234567890"; // Conjunto de elementos validos a obtener

// posición aleatoria del elemento que va a ser elegido
var posicion = 0 + Math.floor(Math.random() * misElementos.length);

// captura del elemento de la posición seleccionada
var num1 = misElementos.charAt(posicion);

// Eliminar elemento del conjunto para no repetirlo
misElementos = misElementos.replace(num1, "");

// posición aleatoria del elemento que va a ser elegido
posicion = 0 + Math.floor(Math.random() * misElementos.length);

// captura del elemento de la posición seleccionada
var num2 = misElementos.charAt(posicion);

// Eliminar elemento del conjunto para no repetirlo
misElementos = misElementos.replace(num2, "");

...
```

Nota: El ejemplo te da 2 números, pero puedes seguir para obtener mas o hacerlo en un bucle.

Nota: si inicializas misElementos con el abecedario ("ABCDEFG....XYZ") obtendras uno de esos elementos...

Con éste método, tienes mas flexibilidad y más variedad. Tu imaginación será el único límite (y el número de elementos dentro de la variable inicial)

;)

EDITO:

Si quieres que tu código quede más limpio y sencillo, repitiendo menos lineas de código, puedes definir una función para obtener un valor del conjunto de elementos, siendo la variable de elementos una variable "global", quedando de la siguiente manera, usando tu ejemplo inicial:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
      var alargada = $('.resultado').length;
    
      // Conjunto de elementos validos a obtener
      var elementos = "123456789"; 

      $(".numeroclicat1").text(getRandom());
      $(".numeroclicat2").text(getRandom());
      $(".numeroclicat3").text(getRandom());
      $(".numeroclicat4").text(getRandom());

      function getRandom(){
          // posición aleatoria del elemento que va a ser elegido
          var posicion = 0 + Math.floor(Math.random() * elementos.length);
   
          // captura del elemento de la posición seleccionada
          var num = elementos.charAt(posicion);

          // Eliminar elemento del conjunto para no repetirlo
          elementos = elementos.replace(num, "");
   
          return num;
        }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-8 actividad2 baseNumeros">
                            <div class="pantalla">
                                <label class="pres">ONE</label> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="resultados">
                                 <button class="resultado BotonReinoNumeros r1">
                                        <label class="clicar numeroclicat1"></label>
                                 </button>
                                <button class="resultado BotonReinoNumeros r2">
                                    <label class="clicar numeroclicat2"></label>
                                </button>
                                <button class="resultado BotonReinoNumeros r3">
                                   <label class="clicar numeroclicat3"></label>
                                </button>
                                 <button class="resultado BotonReinoNumeros r4">
                                    <label class="clicar numeroclicat4"></label>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                           
                    <div class="progress BarraAcitivdad2">
                            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info progress-bar-striped active PNumerosA" 
                            role="progressbar"></div>
                    </div>
                    
 </div>
```

Nota: He aprovechado para que se pueda probar esta solución con el código propuesto.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes generar un numero a la vez y compararlo con lo que ya tienes asi:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
      var alargada = $('.resultado').length;
    
      $(".numeroclicat1").text(1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6));
      var n1 =  $(".numeroclicat1").text();
      var n2 = n1;
          
      while (n1 == n2) {        
          $(".numeroclicat2").text(1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6));
          n2 = $(".numeroclicat2").text();
      }
      var datos = [n1, n2];
      var n3 = n2;
      
      while($.inArray(n3, datos) != -1) {
          $(".numeroclicat3").text(1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6));
          n3 = $(".numeroclicat3").text();
      }
      datos.push(n3);
      var n4 = n3;
      
      while($.inArray(n4, datos) != -1) {
          $(".numeroclicat4").text(1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6));
          n4 = $(".numeroclicat4").text();
      }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-8 actividad2 baseNumeros">
                            <div class="pantalla">
                                <label class="pres">ONE</label> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="resultados">
                                 <button class="resultado BotonReinoNumeros r1">
                                        <label class="clicar numeroclicat1"></label>
                                 </button>
                                <button class="resultado BotonReinoNumeros r2">
                                    <label class="clicar numeroclicat2"></label>
                                </button>
                                <button class="resultado BotonReinoNumeros r3">
                                   <label class="clicar numeroclicat3"></label>
                                </button>
                                 <button class="resultado BotonReinoNumeros r4">
                                    <label class="clicar numeroclicat4"></label>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                           
                    <div class="progress BarraAcitivdad2">
                            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info progress-bar-striped active PNumerosA" 
                            role="progressbar"></div>
                    </div>
                    
 </div>
```